# g++ not finding linker optimization library

Tags: g++

I'm trying to compile a simple c++ program:

```
int main()
{
}
```

That's it. However, I get a linker error:

```
g++: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found compilation terminated
```

Unsurprisingly, this means it can't find the plugin, but I can see it in my file system.  I have been searching and have found that I have to create a symbolic link to it.  But where?  Alternatively, I don't need compiler optimizations at all for this project.  Is it possible to just avoid this plugin altogether?

edit: the output of the commandis:

```
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>"
```

Comment: Where is it in the filesystem?   The g++ version number should be part of the path, like /5/  or /4.7/... Unless you have both versions, you will need to run the same version of g++ as the library.

Comment: g++ is in /usr/bin, while the liblto_plugin is in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/  I should mention that g++ is also version 5.3.1 and the compilation won't work even if I call g++-5

Comment: Then check that g++-5 is not a 32 bit executable (file /usr/bin/g++-5).  You mean /usr/bin/g++ is a link point to /usr/bin/g++-5, not an executable itself?  The 32 bit libraries are in another location, so ...
Also, you are not cross-compiling to 32 bit are you?

Comment: It might also be helpful to include the output of `/usr/bin/g++-5 -xc++ -E -v - < /dev/null` in your question (it should show the g++ build-time options / paths etc.)

Comment: Actually, the output of that command is rather strange.  When I run it as root I get a full page of information.  When I run it as a different user (the user that has this problem), I get # 1 "" # 1 "" # 1 "" # 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4 # 1 "" 2 # 1 "" # 1 ""

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question: it's hard to parse it mentally in comments. But yes, it does look odd. Did you build g++-5 / gcc-5 from source?

Comment: edited, and no, I didn't build from source.

Comment: Oh, and yes, g++ is a 64 bit executable

Comment: Was the g++ diagnostic output really all on a single line? That's even curiouser. Does `dpkg -V gcc-5 g++-5` indicate anything?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I was running it over ssh and something must have gone wrong.  The edit is now in the question.  However, it's still really, really bare.  dpkg is outputting nothing

Comment: /usr/bin/g++ SHOULD be a link to /usr/bin/g++-5  (the default g++ compiler if other versions installed), NOT a real executable.